# How to implement Google Analytics and save daily statistics of a webpage in a database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, google-analytics

I would like to know how to implement Google analytics and make an SQL query from PHP to save daily webpage statistics.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues that you will need to overcome to get this to work. It's not as simple as just adding a file to your site. You will first need to [set up analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/learn/setupchecklist.html) on your site using the javascript that Google provides.

Next you will need to connect to the Google servers either using a PHP API like [GAPI](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/), [curl](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL) or [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_web). You could also try a [JSON](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json) solution. I personally like using the OAuth method for the ease of use. There are [OAuth libraries](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/7700/post/1-Painless-OAuth-with-PHP.html) that can do the heavy lifting, too.

After you have the data you need, you need to add it to the database. You can do this within the PHP for the request, or with AJAX. Both methods are decent. The SQL itself is up to you. If you are using some sort of CMS, try using their database methods instead of writing your own. If you are writing one from scratch, I would suggest the [PDO API](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) in PHP. It takes care of a lot of the security vulnerabilities you usually have with SQL and it's well documented.

All-in-all, there are a lot of moving parts to this process. I would suggest looking for someone who has all, or most, of the leg work already done before diving into it yourself.

Comment: If its only your data you want to access then looking into using a service account would probably be the easiest.  Designing the Data model to support GA data is tricky because of the limit of only 7 dimensions and 11 metrics when extracting data though the API.  If your GA account is a professional account then you will be able to use BigQuery for this and save yourself sometime.